# How to set any Vim file which i create to have appended with #! /usr/bin/env python by default

Tags: python, linux, vim

I am need of a feature to ease my work:

The requirement is whenever i create a file with vim say `vim welcome.py`

The file should open with `#! /usr/bin/env python` appended to it by default.

How to do this. somebody please explain.

Thanks

Comment: I would probably use an [abbreviation](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_abbreviations) for this, e.g. `:ab #py #!/usr/bin/env python`. Not fully automatic, but it would save a lot of typing.

Comment: where to type "ab" command (inside vim ??), so just typing #py to python file will do the job of #!/usr/bin/env python ?

Comment: If you plan on doing this with a lot of different file types you might consider looking at a template plugin

Comment: Yeah that would be better if i get a template kind of thing, but where to start for installing plugin. give some pointeres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add following line to ~/.vimrc

```
autocmd BufNewfile *.py silent! execute '0r! echo "\#\! /usr/bin/env python"'
```

EDITED: this one is more simpler

```
autocmd BufNewfile *.py call append(0,'#! /usr/bin/env python')
```

you can see the help by executing `:help :autocmd` in vim,
or see http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html

Also `append`'s help is in `:help append()`.

Comment: I added the above line to .vimrc and ran source .vimrc it throwed:
au: command not found

Comment: since `~/.vimrc` is configure script for vim, you just need to open some new python file using command such as `vim welcome.py`. no need to execute `source` command.

Comment: awesome!. I was googling around. thanks.!! It did worked, asking just out of curiousity, where to learn these stuffs, i dont have any idea about this. as au is part of vim?? What are all the options that can be set with au:, if you have any pointers , share the link :-)

Comment: Vim's help is great... err... help. `:help :au`. There are almost no limitations on what you can do on an autocommand.

Comment: I updated the question. "where to learn" is very vast question, but it's taken from my own `~/.vimrc` which I created from tips from someone's blog, vim tips wiki( http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki ), an so on, as I use vim for long years.

Comment: I didn't find append(), so my variant was `:autocmd BufNewFile *.py substitute/^/#! \/usr\/bin\/env python/`

Comment: @romainl Can you give the reason why? My guess is that there might have in some new command in next vim version. I updated the answer.

Comment: 1. There's absolutely no benefit in using short names. 2. Think about yourself next year when you won't remember what means what or when other new commands will clash with the current one.